# Boot 32-bit Ubuntu 14.04 from USB Stick on Windows 8.1(64-bit)

Tags: usb, 64-bit, uefi

So I have a3 32-bit Ubuntu image file and I want to boot it from my USB stick. I have already made a bootable stick but whenever I go into my UEFI menu and Choose 'Use a device', I see nothing.

Is it because I'm booting a 32-bit Ubuntu on my 64-bit Windows 8.1? Or is it something different?

Comment: So my only workaround is to get a 64-bit copy?

Comment: You are not booting Ubuntu on Windows. You don't boot one OS through another unless you are using virtualization. So what you are trying to attempt is dual-booting, where Ubuntu and Windows will run alongside each other.

Comment: @Toroidal, Yes, I want to dual boot but I am not able to as my boot menu does not recognize the USB Drive.

Comment: Have you tried putting the USB Drive at the top of the Boot Order in the BIOS settings?

Comment: @Toroidal, that's the problem. My boot order shows 3 things only, Windows, IPv4, IPv6. My USB Stick is not seen at all.

Comment: @XZYoda12: Have you tried putting the USB Drive into other USB ports in your computer as it could just be a faulty port?

Comment: @Toroidal, No, I have tried all ports. Do I really need to get the 64-bit? ( I have a really slow net :( )

Comment: @Toroidal, OK. But if I change my Boot from UEFI to Legacy, then will it work. I want to Try Ubuntu from the USB Stick and not install it on my HDD.

Comment: **You need the 64-bit version!**  @user68186 Could you please convert that to an answer so that schmucks like me who go around hunting for unanswered questions don't have to look at this one any more.  ;-)  (And I'll upvote if you drop me a note and it's a good one too!)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**All Windows 8 and above computers come with UEFI**

UEFI is the new thing that replaced BIOS in these computer. UEFI can be set to Legacy (BIOS) mode, but then Windows 8 and above won't boot. To dual-boot the computer with Windows 8 and Ubuntu, you have to keep the UEFI in its native mode. **32-bit Ubuntu is not compatible with UEFI.**

To dual-boot a computer that came pre-installed with Windows 8 or above, you will need 64-bit Ubuntu.

See [Installing Ubuntu Alongside a Pre-Installed Windows with UEFI](https://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-windows-8-64-bit-system-uefi-supported) for detailed instructions on how to prep the computer for dualboot.

Hope this helps